# using PHP within WAMP- how can I create new directories on my local drives?

Tags: php, apache, permissions, wamp

I am trying to use PHP within my WAMP environment to create new directories (checking if they exists first) on a local drive (U:) which is mapped to a media server (\tr-svrwc-fms)- with no success:  I receive a 403 error.

I've tried creating directory Aliases:

```
Alias /vid "tr-svrwc-fms//" 

<Directory "tr-svrwc-fms//">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and also:

```
Alias /vid "U:" 

<Directory "U:">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride all 
     Order Allow, Deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've even tried modifying the root directory settings in httpd.conf to "Allow from all".

my WAMP server version is 2.2 with Apache version 2.2.21

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that with WAMP installed on my local hard drive, the Apache server (as configured) does not allow for communication outside of the WAMP root folder due to permissions.

This type of communication can however be accomplished via a PHP shell script on the Command Line which doesn't route through the Apache Server.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to only use only UNC paths for network resources in httpd.conf

The syntax should look something like this:

```
Alias /vid "//laptop1/vid"
<Directory "//laptop1/vid">
  ...
</Directory
```

Where `laptop1` of course will be different in your case.